# Order by highest and lowest

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

my question is related to a Select, i want to order a field by ASC and DESC, look at the example:

I have the table Products, the field that i want to order is called Price, so, i know i can do this:

```
SELECT Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC.
```

But i want to see the highest price and the lowest, for the highest i know i can do:

```
 SELECT Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC limit 1;
```

So, how can i select the highest value and the lowest, both in 1 select?

I also want to select the name of the product with highest value and the product with the lowest.

Regards.

Comment: Do you just want the price or the whole row featuring this price? And how would you break ties (multiple rows sharing the lowest / highest)? Pick an arbitrary one? Return all peers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show all the products with the maximum price or with the minimum price:

```
SELECT Products.*
FROM Products
WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM Products)
      OR Price = (SELECT MIN(Price) FROM Products)
```

Or maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  Products.*,
  m.mx As Highest,
  m.mn As Lowest,
  CASE WHEN Products.Price = m.mx THEN 'Max' ELSE 'Min' END As Is_Max_or_Min
FROM
  Products INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Price) mx, MIN(Price) mn
    FROM Products
  ) m ON Products.Price IN (m.mx, m.mn)
```

If you want them on the same row, and if there's only one product with the maximum price and only one with the minimum, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  m.Lowest, p1.Name Name_Lowest,
  m.Highest, p2.Name Name_Highest
FROM
  (SELECT MIN(Price) Lowest, MAX(Price) Highest FROM Products) m
  INNER JOIN Products p1 ON m.Lowest = p1.Price
  INNER JOIN Products p2 ON m.Highest = p2.Price
LIMIT 1
```

Or if you just need something easyer, you could use this:

```
(SELECT 'Max' Is_Max_Or_Min, Products.*
 FROM Products ORDER BY Price DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Min', Products.*
 FROM Products ORDER BY Price LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: @Tennosuke i've updated my last query, i think is this what you are looking for... pls let me know if it's okay :)

Comment: is it so hard? there is no easier way?

Comment: @Tennosuke i edited again, i think the easier way is the last one

Answer (score 4):

What about use of simple `MIN` and `MAX` aggregate function

```
SELECT MAX(Price) as MaxPrice, MIN(Price) as MinPrice FROM Products
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price DESC limit 1;` ??

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see both highest and lowest price, use this query:

```
select highest, lowest from
(
SELECT Price as highest FROM Products ORDER BY Price DESC limit 1;
SELECT Price as lowest FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC limit 1;
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
SELECT MIN(Price) LowestPrice, MAX(Price) HighestPrice FROM Products
```

But in some cases, you may wish to use a `UNION` statement:

```
(SELECT 'Lowest'  type, Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price ASC  LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT 'Highest' type, Price FROM Products ORDER BY Price DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: And now a little more difficult, besides the price if I want the name of the product with highest and lowest? What do you think?